# Should I upgrade to Apache2 with php website?

Tags: php, apache

I have a webserver which runs Apache 1.3 and php 4.x

I was wondering if upgrading Apache and PHP to the latest version will improve performance.

On the web, I found that Apache2 is slower in serving php pages.

is it true?
is it better to stay with Apache 1.X?

thanks

Comment: When Apache 2 was first released nearly ten years ago now, it was fractionally slower at serving php; but things have changed in the PHP and Apache world since then. The PHP SAPI has been improved a little in that time.... I wouldn't base my judgement on 10-years out-of-date performance stats

Comment: Upgrading is not that easy. this will probably break my code. I need to test it. I'm concerned about the performance. is it sure that latest apache won't hurt performance?
thanks

Comment: I didn't say upgrading was easy.... I said don't make a judgement based on out-of-date perfomance stats.... number 1 consideration should be security, number 2 the fact that performance will be better these days (especially as you can use apc and other modern features of PHP)

Answer (score 5):

From [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/):

> You are looking at the documentation for the 1.3 version of the Apache HTTP Server, which is no longer maintained, and has been declared "end of life".

Upgrade ASAP so you aren't caught out with a security problem.

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely upgrade to Apache 2 and PHP 5.3 at least. Support for both PHP 4 and Apache 1.3 are gone.

Answer (score 4):

It's absolutely essential to keep Apache and PHP updated so as to avoid potential security problems.

If you're worried about the speed of Apache, you might want to consider [Nginx](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cts=1331229447029&ved=0CDsQFjAA&url=http://nginx.org/&ei=BvNYT8yMNuPl0QGomuWwDw&usg=AFQjCNET0pbG6EgugGO8AcWE3ljbHBoHPA).

Whatever you do, don't keep old versions of Apache and PHP on your server.

LAMP is the most common configuration out there right now for web applications, and as such is subject to more concerted efforts by malicious individuals who are trying to find vulnerabilities in PHP and Apache. As a result, both have received many, many security updates since the versions you mention, and you would be wise to upgrade ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Apache 2  offers a number of improvements over the previous version which results in enhanced stability and performance.

http://www.mybestratedwebhosting.com/best-web-hosting-tips/introduction-to-apache-2.html